# MQTT broker inside C application

Tags: c, mqtt

Currently, I am using Raspberry Pi on which I am hosting mosquitto MQTT broker and a separate C application that connects and subscribes to localhost. It is a wrapper of what I actually needed. 
I actually need an MQTT broker running inside a C application from where I can control what client IDs can connect. Is there any way to achieve it?

Comment: Why would you not just use userid/password to control which clients connect??  Seems like overkill for something any MQTT Broker already does.  Anyone can fake a clientId on the connect, so for sure, your requirement is not for security reasons.

Comment: Each client connects with a unique ID. I need to consult DB if I should allow a particular client to connect or not.

Answer (score 0):

Mosquitto provides a plugin interface that allows you to control which clients can connect and which topics they can publish/subscribe to.

Normally you would not control access by client id as this can be easily spoofed, instead you should probably be using username/password (or client certificates) to identify the clients.

There are example plugins that store this information in a database so it can be updated dynamically